# Class has virtual method but non virtual destructor C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, methods, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GNU compiler warning “class has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127426/gnu-compiler-warning-class-has-virtual-functions-but-non-virtual-destructor)

I am writing an interface for two classes and I get the warning in the title.
Here's the code:

```
class GenericSymbolGenerator {
   protected:                     // <== ok 
    ~GenericSymbolGenerator(void) {}

   public:
    virtual GenericSymbolTableCollection* generateSymbolTableCollection(GenericSymbolTableCollection *gst) = 0;
    GenericSymbolGenerator(void) {}
    // ~GenericSymbolGenerator(void) {} // <== warning if used
};

class PascalPredefinedSymbolGenerator : public GenericSymbolGenerator {
   protected:
    ~PascalPredefinedSymbolGenerator(void) {} // <== ok

   public:
    GenericSymbolTableCollection* generateSymbolTableCollection(GenericSymbolTableCollection *pst); // initializes *pst
    PascalPredefinedSymbolGenerator(void) {}
    // ~PascalPredefinedSymbolGenerator(void) {} <== warning if used
};

class PascalSymbolGenerator : public GenericSymbolGenerator {
    protected:
         ~PascalSymbolGenerator(void) {} // <== ok

    public:
     GenericSymbolTableCollection* generateSymbolTableCollection(GenericSymbolTableCollection *st); // initializes st
     PascalSymbolGenerator(void) {}
     // ~PascalSymbolGenerator(void) {} // <== warning if used
};
```

As long as the constructor/destructor is void there is no issue in declaring the destructor as protected. The problem arises when the class makes use of the heap(the destructor being declared as protected there is no way of freeing the class from the "outside" making the object "indestructible").
    Is there a more convenient approach(aside from going public all the way)?

Comment: Why do you want to make the destructor protected?

Comment: It is only a scenario in case the interface must be completely restricted to the user.

Comment: > Can you clarify your problem even further? > Why do you want a public constructor & a protected destructor? > As the destructor should be virtual .. so that when you destroy the Object of the child class, it calls the destructors of the base classes.

Comment: It's only an example(my interface constructors/destructors are all void). I was interested in a case in which they are not.

Comment: @Sebi, I'm not quite sure that I follow your reasoning. Are you saying that you want to restrict the usage of your object hierarchy to allowing only the use of instances of the derived class? If so, making the destructor protected is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I intend to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Classes for use as polymorphic bases should have either a virtual destructor or a protected destructor.

The reason is that if you have a public, non-virtual destructor, then pretty much any use of it by an external user of the class is unsafe. For example:

```
GenericSymbolGenerator *ptr = new PascalPredefinedSymbolGenerator();
delete ptr; // behavior is undefined, we tried to call the base class destructor
```

By marking the destructor `protected`, you prevent the user from deleting a `PascalPredefinedSymbolGenerator` object via the base class. By making the destructor public and `virtual`, you get defined behavior when the user deletes through the base class. So pick one of those options.

Comment: Declaring the destructor virtual is more useful in my case. Doesn't declaring the destructor as protected prevent the instantiated derived objects from being deleted?

Comment: @Sebi: no, it only prevents them from being deleted via a pointer-to-base. They can still be deleted via a pointer-to-derived. If your derived classes are hidden from users, who just call some factory function that gives them back a smart pointer that knows what type to delete it as -- then you'd use the `protected` destructor.

Comment: @Sebi FWIW, this is the correct answer to your question, not the one you selected.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I've got it now.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that the compiler is correct to warn you about the non-virtual destructor in the base class. You have created a class that is clearly intended as the root of an inheritance hierarchy, but by making the base class destructor non-virtual, you've broken your ability to delete an object by pointer to the base class (as all that will be executed is the destructor of the base class, so no derived class specific actions will be taken). This is considered a really bad idea in C++ as you essentially break the implementation of polymorphism when it comes to this object hierarchy.

As you mentioned in your comments, your intent is to use GenericSymbolGenerator as an interface and force the user to instantiate and use derived classes containing the actual implementation code. The canonical way to declare an interface in C++ is to declare at least one function on the interface as a pure virtual function. This prohibits you from instantiating the base class, but still create instantiable derived classes. You've already done this by declaring `generateSymbolTableCollection()` as a pure virtual function in your base class. So all you need to do is make the destructor virtual as it really has to be virtual in this particular scenario.

Also, as an aside, the canonical signatures for the default constructor and destructor are normally written without using "void" as a parameter, just use the empty parentheses instead.

Comment: Making the destructor protected (or private) means client code can never delete the derived class object through a base class pointer. So having a virtual destructor is not necessary in this case. Refer to the linked dupe.

Comment: I've gone through the dupe. The destructor there is also void. That's why I asked a new question.

Comment: @Sebi What do you mean by `destructor is void`? Do you mean it's trivial, i.e. the body is empty?

Comment: It has default implementation(does not alter class members/memory).

Comment: The destructor you put into the class is not the default implementation (that one is provided by the compiler). You put in an empty destructor, which is different.

Comment: @Timo didn't know that.I've made the destructor virtual and it's all good.

Comment: @Sebi It doesn't matter whether the destructor is trivial or not, if it is non-virtual and you delete a derived class object through a pointer to your base class, behavior is undefined. However, this is not an issue in your case since your base class destructor is protected. The answer above ignores this fact completely and so it is not entirely correct.

Comment: +1, if only because of the `Also, as an aside, the canonical signatures for the default constructor and destructor are normally written without using "void" as a parameter, just use the empty parentheses instead.` comment.

Comment: -1, because `delete`ing a base pointer is UB, not some half-destruction.